# Рекламный идентификатор в Android

Tags: android, google-play, admob, реклама

Сегодня в консоли разработчика увидел новое сообщение со следующим текстом:

"В соответствии с правилами программы для разработчиков приложений Google Play с 1 августа 2014 г. во всех новых загружаемых приложениях и обновлениях вместо постоянных идентификаторов в любых целях, связанных с рекламой, должен использоваться рекламный идентификатор.".

У меня есть несколько приложений с рекламой от AdMob и WapStart. Кто-нибудь разобрался окончательно, что это все значит? Что нужно делать, чтобы приложение соответствовало новым правилам? Подразумевает ли это новое правило, что пользователь сможет отключать рекламу просто сняв галочку в настройках?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что это значит что гугл собирается отжать рынок сторонних рекламных сервисов :-) и монополизировать право на сбор рекламной статистики на андроидах.

Comment: Ну даже если так. А что нужно сделать разработчику? Рекламу можно будет отключать?

Comment: Можно будет или нельзя отключать - это будет уже решать гугл и рекламные сервисы. Но не думаю что до этого дойдёт, хотя очень хотелось бы - они не будут пилить сук на которых сидят :-)